# VB Type Mismatch 'Return'

Tags: vb6

I want to use a function to return a string however, I keep getting a Type mismatch 'Return' error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Dim myvar
myvar = getMultiLineString()
MsgBox(myvar)

Function getMultiLineString()

    Dim a(3)
    Dim i
    Dim query

    a(1)   = "test line 1"
    a(2)   = "test line 2"
    a(3)   = "test line 3"

    query = a(1)

    For i=2 to 3
        query = query & VbCrLf &  a(i)
    next

    MsgBox(query)
    Return query

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
Return query
```

You would use "name_of_function = value_it_should_return":

```
getMultiLineString = query
```

Comment: That works, thank you!  Can you explain why the original syntax did not work?  Or can you explain if there is an option to accomplish the same using the 'return' approach?

Comment: Well it would appear your code is really vbscript, which does not have a return statement.  VB6 does.